Is forcing correlation between parameter values allowed in bayesian regression
I am using bayesian nonlinear regression in brms to fit some model parameters, and I'm running into some issues getting MCMC chains to converge. I know this is because of some model specification issues and I'm looking for a way to incorporate some assumptions into my priors or model specification that will help avoid this issue.
The data: the response variable $C_{r[i]}$ is the fraction of a chemical i remaining after an experiment, and $conc$ is the initial concentration of the chemical. There are about 500 different chemicals measured in the dataset, with 9 observations per chemical. $C_{r[i]}$ is a positive number, where values less than 1 indicate a net decrease and values greater than 1 indicate a net increase in the chemical during the experiment, and $conc$ values range from 0.1 to 1.
Generally, I'm fitting functions of the form
$$
C_{r[i]} ~ 1 + exp(b_i) - f(conc)
$$
Where $b_i$ is a random effect for each different chemical and $f(conc)$ is some function of the concentration. Parameters in $f(conc)$ are generally transformed in a way that ensures they are positive, so $exp(b_i)$ represents the estimated gains and $f(conc)$ represents the estimated losses. Of course, there are issues fitting this model because if $b_i$ and $f(conc)$ can take any value then there are infinite plausible parameter combinations. Generally, my way around this has been to structure $f(conc)$ so that the maximum possible value is 1, which constrains parameter values enough for MCMC chains to converge.
Now, I'm trying to fit a version of this where $f(conc)$ is a piecewise function. Below some threshold $t_i$  it's value is 0, and above it takes the form
$$
f(conc) = \begin{cases} 
          0 & conc < t_i \\
          \frac{a*conc}{1 + b_1*conc^2} & conc > t_i  \end{cases}
$$
Where is a function of the chemical property NOSC. The threshold $t_i$ would be a random effect of chemical identity.
The issue is that particularly for chemicals where $C_{r[i]}$ > 1, it is equally plausible that $t_i$  is low, and a is also low, or that $t_i$ is high, and $f(conc)$ = 0. Because the model has no reason to suspect either one more, it doesn't converge and I get poor estimates.
Now, I think a way around this might be to specify some relationship between $t_i$ and $b_i$. Essentially, when $C_{r[i]}$ is high, I'm skeptical of low values for $t_i$. Instead, I think it's more likely that $conc < t_i$ and $f(conc) = 0$. So essentially, I think that $t_i$ and $b_i$ are correlated somewhat.
I've found a way to code this that gets a convergent MCMC chain, but I'm concerned about whether it's valid, or if there's a better way. I've been following the example here for specifying piecewise functions in brms. My idea is to fit a random effect, where both $b_i$ and $t_i$ are functions of the effect. $b_i$ is the exponential function of the effect (to keep it positive) and $t_i$ is transformed to a value between 0 and 2 by an inverse logit function (we don't really have power to detect $t_i$ over 1, so answers over 1 are all the same pretty much). So what happens is we end up with the random effect influencing both $b_i$ and $t_i$ positively, with the slope of the relationship depending on an additional parameter $z$, which in one version is a fixed effect, and in another version is an additional random effect, so that there is always a positive relationship, but the slope varies depending on the chemical. The MCMC chains converge more easily when I do it this way, but I'm not sure if it's really good practice.
My code then looks like this:
chem_priors = 
  prior(normal(-1, 0.25), nlpar = "b") +
  prior(normal(1.5, 0.25), nlpar = "k0") +
  prior(normal(1, 0.25), nlpar = "k1") +
  prior(exponential(1), nlpar = "b1", lb = 0) +
  prior(normal(0, 1), nlpar = "z") +
  prior(exponential(1), class = "sigma") +
  prior(exponential(10), class = "sd", nlpar = "b") 

chem_sb_ce = brm(data = md, family = lognormal(),
                 bf(frac_remain ~ (1  +  exp(b)) - 
                   step(1 - t) * (a * conc)/(1 + (b1 * conc^2)),
                    nlf(a ~ inv_logit(k0 + k1*nosc_adj)),
                    k0 ~ 1,
                    k1 ~ 1,
                    b1 ~ 1,
                    nlf(t ~ 2*inv_logit(exp(z)*b)),
                    z ~ 1,
                    # alternative: z ~ (1 | chemical),
                    b ~ (1 | chemical),
                    nl = TRUE),
prior = chem_priors,
iter = 1000, warmup = 500, chains = 4, cores = 4, 
control = list(adapt_delta = 0.99))

So is it valid to specify the model this way, with the same random effect working in two parts of the model? Is there a better way to just specify some kind of covariance prior for two parameters?
